# How could I use canvas to past one image into an other?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, canvas, html5-canvas

I would like to past one image into an other image with a transparent box.

So it's not only copy and past some image into an other. Also how could I transform the image to fit in the other image.
*Example: placeit.net*

How could I use Canvas, JQuery or other for that? Thanks for any examples.

**UPDATE:**
I didn't want to be spoon-fed some code. Only one example or documentation about transforming like placeit.net.

Comment: Yes, it is possible. Does that answer your question?

Comment: Have you tried anything yourself. If you have then please show us what you have tried. Otherwise it seems like you want to be spoon-fed some code

Comment: I tried it with ImageMagick. But it seems not possible - I also use this code http://android-ui-utils.googlecode.com/hg/asset-studio/dist/device-frames.html - But thats only copy one image into an other and not transforming like placeit.net

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is seems to be advertising for a company rather than a question.


Comment: +GameAlchemist It's the opposite: The company has restricted their service and I would like to create an alternative...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Yes, you can do placeit.net type effects using html canvas.**

Look at compositing to draw a second image only where a first image is transparent.

Look at transformations to:

- Rotate your second image into place,
- Skew your second image to fit the angle of your first image.

You can do image filters (mostly from 3rd party solutions).

- A good blur filter: http://www.quasimondo.com/StackBlurForCanvas/StackBlurDemo.html

You can add text to your presentation with context.fillText

Comment: Thanks for your answer! Are there any good references / documentations for the first two hints?

Comment: Compositing and transformations are built into html canvas, so any html canvas reference will get you started.  For compositing, check out context.globalCompositeOperation = "destination-over".  For rotation, check out context.translate plus context.rotate.  For skewing, check out context.transform.  This site has examples: http://www.html5canvastutorials.com/advanced/html5-canvas-advanced-tutorials-introduction/  Good luck with your project :)